# Check for existence of a keyword within a code string

Tags: javascript, string, loops, parseint

I’m loading the contents of a JS file using FileReader and dumping the results into a textarea container. I then want to run some checks on the actual JS file.

I know there are probably tools out there for this already (or better ways), but this is for a closed-environment project.

After the textarea contains the content of the JS file as one large string, I need to loop the string and find all instances of `parseInt()` to check if they have been supplied with a radix.

I would provide code, but I have nothing working at this point. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd probably use Esprima--you have source, treat it as such rather than relying on trying to get reliable data from treating it like a string.

Comment: Thanks, but not what I'm looking for. I'm needing to loop a string

Comment: You have JS source, and you're trying to locate specific method calls. Treat it as JS source and don't pretend it's plain text: parse it, identify the calls, fix them. If you want to do it the fragile, simplistic, "won't handle all cases" way, it's a trivial matter of regex or search, assuming (a) no calls are within a string, (b) there aren't arbitrary expressions inside the `parseInt` that would confuse your regex/string search, etc. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will search the string value of your `<textarea>` element for `parseInt()` and output the occurences, with radix where applicable:

```js
var textareaValue = 'var func = function(){' +
                    'var i = parseInt(1,1);' +
                    'var j = parseInt(10, 10);' +
                    'var k = parseInt(3) + j;' +
                    '};';
occurences = textareaValue.match(/parseInt\(.+?(, ?\d+)?\)/g);
occurences.forEach(function(occurence){
    var hasRadix = /, ?\d+\)$/.test(occurence);
    document.body.innerHTML += '<p>"' + occurence + '" has ' +
                           (hasRadix ? 'a' : 'no') + ' radix' +
                           (hasRadix ? ' (' + occurence.match(/, ?(\d+)\)$/)[1] + ')' : '') +
                           '.</p>';
});
```

> Note that this is no actual syntax interpretation, it’s merely text analysis. You will have to go from the result, which comprises all the occurences of `parseInt()` as strings. Also, JavaScript allows whitespace, comments, expressions and other witchcraft at the text passage in question. You might to have to check for *anything*.

The actual regex [**`/parseInt\(.+?(, ?\d+)?\)/g`**](https://regex101.com/r/rB3zA9/2) will demand…

- `parseInt(` at the beginning of the match
- any characters (might need to be expanded to include brackets, etc. by `:punct:`)
- as optional group, determining whether a radix is supplied or not:

  - a comma, an optional space (might need to respond to any number of whitespace using `*`)
  - at least one digit (might need to limit to `{1,2}`, because only 2 to 36 are valid)
- a trailing closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

The following function should be able to tell the difference between usages of `parseInt` with radix versus its usages without radix by simplistic regex matching:

```
function have_radix(str){
     parseIntRegex = /parseInt\(.+?\)/g;
     parseIntRegexWithRadix = /parseInt\(.+?(,.+?\))/g;
     indices = [];
     while ( (result = parseIntRegex.exec(str)) ) {
         indices.push(result.index);
     }
     count = indices.length;
     indices = []; 
     while ( (result = parseIntRegexWithRadix.exec(str)) ) {
         indices.push(result.index);
     }
     diff = count - indices.length;
    return diff;
}
```